# How do I replace a character with a string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to input a String that contains a single * character, then a second String. The * will be replaced by the second String. So for example, if the user enters the Strings "d*g" and "in", the program outputs ding.
The original String must contain only letters of the alphabet, capital or lowercase, spaces and tab, and a single *. The replacement String may be any legal String in Java.
If the first String does not contain a * “Error: no *“ should be output.
If the first String contains anything other than letters of the alphabet, spaces or tabs then “Error: Incorrect characters“ should be printed. If the first String does not have a * I do not have to check for incorrect characters, only “Error: no *“ should be output.

What I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;


class Main{

     public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

char letter;
int i;

  System.out.println("Enter the first String:");
String wc = scan.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Enter the replacement String:");
String replace = scan.nextLine();
String my_new_str = wc.replaceAll("*", replace);
for (i = 0; i < wc.length(); i++)
        {
          letter = wc.charAt(i);

          if (! (letter == '*')){
            System.out.println("Error: no *");}
          System.out.println(""+ my_new_str);







}

}
}
```

Comment: since `*` is a special meta char, you need to escape * like `String my_new_str = wc.replaceAll("\\*", replace);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you wanted [`String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) (not `replaceAll` that takes a regular expression).

```
String my_new_str = wc.replaceAll("*", replace);
```

should be

```
String my_new_str = wc.replace("*", replace);
```

You can test it like

```
String wc = "d*g";
String replace = "in";
System.out.println(wc.replace("*", replace));
```

And get (as requested)

```
ding
```

Comment: That fixed the concatenation issue but the program is returning:               Error: no *
ding
ding
Error: no *
ding